# Pass values to php script through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to display the results of a php file based off of the input values of a div/form.

I have the following JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#ranksubmit').click(function() { 
            $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "queryrankings.php",
            data:  $("#query-form").serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                $(".results-table").html(result);
            }

        });
            //return false;
      }); 

    });
</script>
```

And it is supposed to pass the values of this div to the php script queryrankings.php :

```
 <div class="form-horizontal" id="query-form"  >
                <fieldset>

                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend class = "text-center">Query Rankings<hr></legend>

                <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ranktype">Ranking Type:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="ranktype-0">
                      <input type="radio" name="ranktype" id="ranktype-0" value="1" checked="checked">
                      Author
                    </label> 
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="ranktype-1">
                      <input type="radio" name="ranktype" id="ranktype-1" value="2">
                      University
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Select Basic -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="startyear">From:(ie. 2010)</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="startyear" name="startyear" class="form-control">
                      <option value="2010">2010</option>
                      <option value="2011">2011</option>
                      <option value="2012">2012</option>
                      <option value="2013">2013</option>
                      <option value="2014">2014</option>
                      <option value="2015">2015</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Select Basic -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="endingyear">To:(ie. 2015)</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="endingyear" name="endingyear" class="form-control">
                      <option value="2010">2010</option>
                      <option value="2011">2011</option>
                      <option value="2012">2012</option>
                      <option value="2013">2013</option>
                      <option value="2014">2014</option>
                      <option value="2015" selected="selected">2015</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>


                <!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="journalselection">Journal Selection:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="journalselection-0">
                      <input type="radio" name="journalselection" id="journalselection-0" value="all" checked="checked" onclick="CheckBoxes(1)" >
                      All Journals
                    </label> 
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="journalselection-1">
                      <input type="radio" name="journalselection" id="journalselection-1" value="basket" onclick="CheckBoxes(2)">
                      AIS Basket of Journals
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="journalselection-2">
                      <input type="radio" name="journalselection" id="journalselection-2" value="top2" onclick="CheckBoxes(3)">
                      Top 2 Journals
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="journalselection-3">
                      <input type="radio" name="journalselection" id="journalselection-3" value="custom" onclick="CheckBoxes(4)">
                      Custom Selection
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>


                <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="journals">Journals:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="journals-0">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="journals" id="journals-0" value="misq" checked onclick="CustomSelection()">
                      MISQ
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="journals-1">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="journals" id="journals-1" value="isr" checked onclick="CustomSelection()">
                      ISR
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="journals-2">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="journals" id="journals-2" value="jmis" checked onclick="CustomSelection()">
                      JMIS
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="journals-3">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="journals" id="journals-3" value="jais" checked onclick="CustomSelection()">
                      JAIS 
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="journals-4">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="journals" id="journals-4" value="ejis" checked onclick="CustomSelection()">
                      EJIS
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="journals-5">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="journals" id="journals-5" value="isj" checked onclick="CustomSelection()">
                      ISJ
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="journals-6">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="journals" id="journals-6" value="jsis" checked onclick="CustomSelection()">
                      JSIS
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="journals-7">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="journals" id="journals-7" value="jit" checked onclick="CustomSelection()">
                      JIT
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="journals-8">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="journals" id="journals-8" value="dss" checked onclick="CustomSelection()">
                      DSS
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="journals-9">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="journals" id="journals-9" value="iandm" checked onclick="CustomSelection()">
                      I&M
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Select Basic -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">COMING SOON!  Category:</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select disabled id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
                      <option value="1">Region, NCAA Conference, & More!</option>
                      <option value="2">N/A</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ranksubmit"></label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button id="ranksubmit"  class="btn btn-default-border wow tada">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

                </fieldset>
                </div>
```

When I try to `$_POST` the values inside of the php script it doesn't work. Shouldn't it be reading in the values in this div?

Here is the php. It will return a regular print statement but it will not print the posted variable I assume because it isn't reading anything in:

```html
<?php

  $dbHost = "localhost";
  $dbUsername = "user_rw";
  $dbPassword = "";
  $dbName = "webdb";

  // Create connection
  $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
  // Check connection
  if ($db->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
  } else {
  
  $type = $_POST['ranktype'];
  print $type;

  }
?>
```

I am using a `<div>` instead of `<form>` because I do not want the page to reload when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: can you provide your php code also ?

Comment: try to pass a simple object as `data: {foo:'bar'}`

Comment: sorry @webdeb I'm new to this and don't know how I would even print that in the php script.

Comment: echo var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="query-form"  > ...</div>
```

should be `form tag`

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="query-form"  > .... </form>
```

**Updated.**

```
$('#ranksubmit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
 // the rest of the code
});
```

Use `<input type="button"/>`, or `e.preventDefault()` or`return false` to prevent form from submitting.

Comment: because of `$('form').serialize()` ?

Comment: because of this `<div></div>`

Comment: i don't want to use form because it will reload the page if i use that

Comment: @TaylorClark no you should use `event.preventDefault()` it will prevent reloading..

Comment: @webdeb Thanks a ton!

Comment: use like @webdeb said, or use button type instead rather than type `submit` or return false